# How to associate file extension in Windows 10 to arbitrary command?

Tags: windows-10, java, file-association, file-extension

I would like to set FXML files opened with Gluon Scene Builder, which exists in the form of JAR file. So, in old good Windows I would associate these files with command like

```
javaw -jar PATHTOSceneBuilder.jar %1
```

How to do it now? Only the constant list of programs proposed:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used Java. But based on your command-line, I made a .REG file.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.fxml]
@="fxmlfile"  

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\fxmlfile\shell\open\command]
@="javaw.exe -jar PATHTOSceneBuilder.jar \"%1\""
```

That assumes javaw.exe and pathtoscenebuilder.jar are included in Path or else error would occur when double-clicking .fxml files.

(Alternately, you may use a 3rd party utility to create/modify associations. [FileTypesMan - Alternative to 'File Types' manager of Windows](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html))